# Error when ingesting files in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to ingest a simple point shapefile in GEE from the asset tab of the Code Editor
The program sent me back this error

```
"Task details: Asset ingestion: users/giuliocst/JesrAdbachPOINT

State: Failed

Started: 1m ago (2018-11-07 16:34:10 +0100)

Runtime: 7s

Id: LVKE25EJBW5AWJ6AVYPDCVKV

Error: File access denied: 'E1yLz1m5tKhVI1Io/Jesr Adbach POINT.shp'."
```

What I am missing? I am using the same procedure as always

Comment: What exactly is "the same procedure as always"? As a hunch - have you tried removing the spaces from the filename of the shapefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earth Engine table ingestion currently fails for filenames that include spaces. I've filed a bug about this, but in the meanwhile the workaround is to replace the spaces with underscores (or some other character).

Answer (score 1):

Just a reminder, GEE will also report file access denied if your code editor account is not the one registered for GEE. Like I have two gmail accounts and one registered with GEE but another didn't. I encounter the error again and again until I realized the account issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and realized that the solution is to make sure your shapefile name has no spaces at all between the alphabets/numbers.

In your case you should replace your 'Jesr Adbach POINT.shp' to 'JesrAdbachPOINT.shp' or like Typer said, replace the spaces with underscores like this: 'Jesr_Adbach_POINT.shp'