# Google Earth Engine unable to ingest shapefile, transformation fail?

Tags: arcmap, google-earth-engine

Tried importing [Longhurst regions](http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=22538) shapefiles into Google Earth Engine, running into error:

```
Error: Unable to transform edge (179.998129, 90.000003 to -0.000936, 90.000003) from GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", DATUM["D_WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]] PLANAR to EPSG:4326.
```

This occurs even after reprojecting the shapefile in ArcMap to WGS 1984 (suggested by [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301716/error-when-ingesting-files-in-google-earth-engine). Wondering if it's data issue. I'm new to GEE and ArcMap.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reproject shapefile in arcmap to ingest it in GEE. I downloaded **ICES_ecoregions.zip** from your first link and unpacked it. Afterward, I selected only the files showed in below image and packed again as *.zip. If you try to ingest with a file different to *.dbf, *.prj, *.shp or *.shx you always will have an error.

[image]

After packed as zip file, I ingested it in 11 minutes; as it can be observed in following image. It is also observed that Feature Collection was imported in a new script and it is a relatively huge file.

[image]